# How to filter the tasks using custom field value - ProjectServer Rest OData API 2013

Tags: odata, custom-fields, sharepoint-2013, project-server

I've been trying to filter the Task collection using custom field called "TaskType" (I've created this one). This custom field has an associated lookup table. So if i query the OData :

> *https://myserver/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('0647003e-dce3-e211-9477-080027efb62d')/IncludeCustomFields/Tasks*

I get the following custom field data:

```
 "Custom_x005f_fe7ff100cee3e2119477080027efb62d":{
   "results":[
     "Entry_960a8ffef3334cc2bfee14a27cf95dbb"
   ]
}
```

since this is an array I can't filter using this field. I can extract names of the assigned custom fields, but not the value.
 so the following query

> *https://PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('0647003e-dce3-e211-9477-080027efb62d')/IncludeCustomFields/Tasks?$select=CustomFields/Name,CustomFields/LookupEntries/Value&$expand=CustomFields,CustomFields/LookupEntries*

would return something like this

```
{
   "CustomFields":{
      "results":[
         {
            "LookupEntries":{
               "results":[
                  {
                     "Value":"Normal"
                  },
                  {
                     "Value":"Auto"
                  },
                  {
                     "Value":"Manual"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Name":"Task Type"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is there any association between Task and its Custom Field Value so that could be used to filter the results?

Using the ProjectData API is not something I want to go into.